# Sending an Array with HTTParty Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sugarcrm, httparty

I'm using the HTTParty Gem to send data to a SugarCRM API.

I managed to successfully authenticate with the API and now I'm looking to create a lead there, by posting data to the API.

I hit a bump when trying to send the name_value_pair fields though, which are in Sugar CRMs Documentation supposed to be send like this --

```
"name_value_list" => array(
    array(
        'name' => 'last_name',
        'value' => 'Victor',
    ),

    array(
        'name' => 'phone_mobile',
        'value' => ‘9999999999’
    ),
),
```

Trying to convert this into Ruby, I got this as my request --

```
response2 = HTTParty.post(base_uri,
        body: {
          method: "set_entry",
          input_type: "JSON",
          response_type: "JSON",
          rest_data: {
            session: session_id,
            module_name: 'Leads',
            name_value_list:
              [
                [
                  'name', 'last_name'
                ],
                [
                  'value', 'Victor'
                ],
              ]
          }.to_json
        },
        debug_output: $stdout
      )
```

However, the CRM API returns me a 500 error. How can I structure this array data so that it mimics the PHP documentation for the `name_value_list` field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp, at "Associative Arrays", and I think the PHP you have is intending for the key/value pairs to be a hash rather than an array.  So I suggest trying this:

```
name_value_list:
   [
      {
         'name' => 'last_name',
         'value' => 'Victor'
      },
   ]
```

(The only change is that the inner square brackets are converted to curly braces.)

Answer (score 0):

Well try to convert original string to `HTTParty`'s one as it is, i.e.:

```
name_value_list:
   [
      [
         'name' => 'last_name',
         'value' => 'Victor'
      ],
   ]
```

Comment: I tried this but still no avail :( This was the JSON object sent - `{"session":"lf4kit2mt7c964ba3eqiok5k34","module_name":"Leads","name_value_list":[["name","last_name"],["value","Victor"]]}`

Comment: @MichaelVictor whch JSON objkect s required?